# Drop duplicate columns when they have the same name and same values in a DataFrame with different types, for example dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Example of my DataFrame (I'm putting it with a divider in commas because the print in the terminal is too big):

```
_item_name_to_attribute_name_overrides,_datetime_created,_datetime_updated,event,elapsed_time,market_count,_data,marketCount,event.id,event.name,event.countryCode,event.timezone,event.openDate
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.184838,2023-02-09 14:25:03.184838,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E020E0>,0.30626821517944336,9,"{'event': {'id': '32092781', 'name': 'Al-Sadd v Al Arabi (QAT)', 'countryCode': 'QA', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T13:40:50.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 9}",9,32092781,Al-Sadd v Al Arabi (QAT),QA,GMT,2023-02-09T13:40:50.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E02650>,0.30626821517944336,12,"{'event': {'id': '32062604', 'name': 'Scheveningen v Katwijk', 'countryCode': 'NL', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-01-28T13:32:48.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 12}",12,32062604,Scheveningen v Katwijk,NL,GMT,2023-01-28T13:32:48.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E02440>,0.30626821517944336,9,"{'event': {'id': '32091628', 'name': 'Al-Oruba v Al Nahdha', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T13:11:14.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 9}",9,32091628,Al-Oruba v Al Nahdha,,GMT,2023-02-09T13:11:14.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E026E0>,0.30626821517944336,9,"{'event': {'id': '32091663', 'name': 'Busoga United v Maroons FC', 'countryCode': 'UG', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T13:05:11.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 9}",9,32091663,Busoga United v Maroons FC,UG,GMT,2023-02-09T13:05:11.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E027A0>,0.30626821517944336,8,"{'event': {'id': '32091662', 'name': 'Wakiso Giants v Kampala City Council', 'countryCode': 'UG', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T13:00:29.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 8}",8,32091662,Wakiso Giants v Kampala City Council,UG,GMT,2023-02-09T13:00:29.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E02890>,0.30626821517944336,5,"{'event': {'id': '32093038', 'name': 'Bodo Glimt v Silkeborg', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T13:00:37.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 5}",5,32093038,Bodo Glimt v Silkeborg,,GMT,2023-02-09T13:00:37.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E02920>,0.30626821517944336,7,"{'event': {'id': '32085575', 'name': 'Al Ittihad (EGY) v Aswan FC', 'countryCode': 'EG', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T12:45:00.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 7}",7,32085575,Al Ittihad (EGY) v Aswan FC,EG,GMT,2023-02-09T12:45:00.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E029E0>,0.30626821517944336,8,"{'event': {'id': '32094567', 'name': 'Chabab Ben Guerir v Rapide Club Oued Zem', 'countryCode': 'MA', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T13:01:31.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 8}",8,32094567,Chabab Ben Guerir v Rapide Club Oued Zem,MA,GMT,2023-02-09T13:01:31.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E02AD0>,0.30626821517944336,10,"{'event': {'id': '32094023', 'name': 'Hapoel Kfar Shelem v Hapoel Marmorek', 'countryCode': 'IL', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T14:00:00.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 10}",10,32094023,Hapoel Kfar Shelem v Hapoel Marmorek,IL,GMT,2023-02-09T14:00:00.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E02B60>,0.30626821517944336,9,"{'event': {'id': '32090014', 'name': 'Al-Batin v Al-Shabab (KSA)', 'countryCode': 'SA', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T13:00:00.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 9}",9,32090014,Al-Batin v Al-Shabab (KSA),SA,GMT,2023-02-09T13:00:00.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E02C50>,0.30626821517944336,7,"{'event': {'id': '32093329', 'name': 'Al Madina Al Monawara SC v La Viena FC', 'countryCode': 'EG', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T13:00:09.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 7}",7,32093329,Al Madina Al Monawara SC v La Viena FC,EG,GMT,2023-02-09T13:00:09.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E02E60>,0.30626821517944336,6,"{'event': {'id': '32091633', 'name': 'Bani Sweif v MS Tamia', 'countryCode': 'EG', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T13:01:15.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 6}",6,32091633,Bani Sweif v MS Tamia,EG,GMT,2023-02-09T13:01:15.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E02DA0>,0.30626821517944336,9,"{'event': {'id': '32091632', 'name': 'El Alominiom v Dayrout', 'countryCode': 'EG', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T13:03:50.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 9}",9,32091632,El Alominiom v Dayrout,EG,GMT,2023-02-09T13:03:50.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E02EF0>,0.30626821517944336,12,"{'event': {'id': '32091344', 'name': 'AC Paradou U21 v NC Magra U21', 'countryCode': 'DZ', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T14:08:25.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 12}",12,32091344,AC Paradou U21 v NC Magra U21,DZ,GMT,2023-02-09T14:08:25.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E02170>,0.30626821517944336,12,"{'event': {'id': '32091347', 'name': 'HB Chelghoum Laid U21 v Cr Belouizdad U21', 'countryCode': 'DZ', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T14:00:00.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 12}",12,32091347,HB Chelghoum Laid U21 v Cr Belouizdad U21,DZ,GMT,2023-02-09T14:00:00.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E02FB0>,0.30626821517944336,12,"{'event': {'id': '32091346', 'name': 'MC Alger U21 v JS Saoura U21', 'countryCode': 'DZ', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T14:05:27.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 12}",12,32091346,MC Alger U21 v JS Saoura U21,DZ,GMT,2023-02-09T14:05:27.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E030A0>,0.30626821517944336,8,"{'event': {'id': '32091637', 'name': 'Misr El Makasa v Kema Aswan', 'countryCode': 'EG', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T13:05:00.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 8}",8,32091637,Misr El Makasa v Kema Aswan,EG,GMT,2023-02-09T13:05:00.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E03160>,0.30626821517944336,12,"{'event': {'id': '32091349', 'name': 'USM Khenchela U21 v CS Constantine U21', 'countryCode': 'DZ', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T14:02:19.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 12}",12,32091349,USM Khenchela U21 v CS Constantine U21,DZ,GMT,2023-02-09T14:02:19.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E03220>,0.30626821517944336,10,"{'event': {'id': '32091348', 'name': 'MC Oran U21 v RC Arba U21', 'countryCode': 'DZ', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T14:05:15.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 10}",10,32091348,MC Oran U21 v RC Arba U21,DZ,GMT,2023-02-09T14:05:15.000Z
{},2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,2023-02-09 14:25:03.186839,<betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources.Event object at 0x000001EDC6E032E0>,0.30626821517944336,8,"{'event': {'id': '32091638', 'name': 'Wadi Degla v Eastern Company SC', 'countryCode': 'EG', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2023-02-09T13:03:29.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 8}",8,32091638,Wadi Degla v Eastern Company SC,EG,GMT,2023-02-09T13:03:29.000Z
```

To remove columns that have the **same name** and **same values**, I do this here:

```python
df = df.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

But, one of my DataFrame columns has dictionaries and another column has an object instance of the "Event" class from the "betfairlightweight.resources.bettingresources" package., I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Testes VSCODE\b.py", line 59, in <module>
    matches_df(trading)
  File "c:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Testes VSCODE\b.py", line 55, in matches_df
    df = df.T.drop_duplicates().T
  File "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6116, in drop_duplicates
    duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, keep=keep)
  File "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6253, in duplicated
    labels, shape = map(list, zip(*map(f, vals)))
  File "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6226, in f
    labels, shape = algorithms.factorize(vals, size_hint=len(self))
  File "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 763, in factorize
    codes, uniques = factorize_array(
  File "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 560, in factorize_array
    uniques, codes = table.factorize(
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5394, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5310, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How can I proceed in this scenario where I don't have just common strings and numbers?

Just for context, in the example there are two columns called `market_count` and their values are exactly the same, so I want to keep only one. But it may happen that the `_data` column (which is where the dictionaries are) is exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I really understand your problem with the `_data` column and the fact that 2 columns have the same name.

But to solve the issue with the `dict`, you can try the `string` conversion

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col_a": [{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}, {"c": 3}],
    "col_b": [{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}, {"c": 3}],
    "col_c": [1, 4, 2],
    "col_d": [3.2, 9.1, 3.5],
    "col_e": [1, 4, 2],
    "col_f": [1, 4, 3],
    "col_g": ["r", "g", "b"],
    "col_h": [{"a": 1}, {"b": 1}, {"c": 2}]
})

# Show kept columns
columns_to_keep = df.T.astype(str).drop_duplicates().index
print(df[columns_to_keep])

# Show dropped columns
columns_to_drop = df.columns.difference(columns_to_keep)
print(df[columns_to_drop])
```

Output

```
      col_a  col_c  col_d  col_f col_g     col_h
0  {'a': 1}      1    3.2      1     r  {'a': 1}
1  {'b': 2}      4    9.1      4     g  {'b': 1}
2  {'c': 3}      2    3.5      3     b  {'c': 2}

      col_b  col_e
0  {'a': 1}      1
1  {'b': 2}      4
2  {'c': 3}      2
```